# How to use Traefik proxy to redirect to different apps in docker

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have two apps in docker:

- App A -> port 3001
- App B -> port 3002

Now I have domain.com.

I want to redirect:

- appa.domain.com to App A
- appb.domain.com to App B

I tried to read the documentation and tried but had no success. The container for App A and B are running. The Traefik says to use docker compose as one way but I just want to keep the old container. Do I directly run the Traefik `./traefik --configFile=traefik.toml` which is one of the way with config file.

I am not sure what to add to the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#using-docker-compose) of Traefik's docker backend?

You can configure the URL at which you expose the apps via a label on the container itself. For instance if you are using docker-compose, you can add something like this:

```
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: Host:appa.domain.com
      traefik.enable: "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to go ahead with Nginx, I'll suggest you go ahead with [jwilder's Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) which will help you do the same thing with Nginx instead of Traefik.

All you need to do is simply run the Nginx reverse proxy container once. After that whenever you spin, say App A all you'll need to do is pass an extra variable in the command like `docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=appa.domain.com  ...` for every container

Comment: do I docker run -e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com -p 3001?
The port 80 is running ngnix and the app is listening on 3001?

Comment: The format is -p hostPort:containerPort. So in this case you could do something like 3001:3001 to map the host 3001 to the container 3001 or the way you defined 3001, it would automatically bind to any available open port on the host machine.

It is better to map it to a port which you have already defined